# Crystal Reports - add results of grouping together

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

Really low level question, but it's been 5 years since I used Crystal Reports and I want to ensure that before I think about using it again that it would be suitable - I think it will.

I have two groups of data - Group 1 is Income, Group 2 is Expenses.  I am looking to create a Profit result by a formula to take the sum of Group 2 away from the sum of Group 1.  If I recall this is quite straightforward, but just throwing this one out there to begin with.

Thanks

Comment: As you said its a straight forward after you place group1 and group2 sum in group footer 1 just take another formula and do a  arithematic subtraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are income and expenses 2 different values of the same field in the database? If so, create a formula like below to storage Income and expenses total values and place it on your group footer

`if {database your field} = "Income" then numbervar Income := {your group total} else numbervar Expenses := {your group total}`

Then subtract them in a second formula placed on your report footer(numbervar Income - numbervar Expenses)